# Component-Information from JAR-File possible?

Tags: ajax, frameworks, jar, toolkit, modularity

I would like to set up a web application with good modularity and would like to use an `AJAX Toolkit/Framework` like GWT or ZK for its VIEW. Component information should be load from various modules-JAR.

Which `AJAX Toolkit/Framework` is able to do this?

Comment: if you need a answer, i spend a bounty...?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.ztemplates.org which is simple and easy to learn. This one allows you to put all related templates, javascript and css into one jar and use it transparently. Means you even have not to care about declaring the needed javascript in your page when using a provided component, as the framework does it for you.